# Why i cannot use some svg in firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, svg

The problem is that I cannot use some inline SVG at all. I noticed about `<object >` and SVG problems in FF. But the fact is that many other ones are working.

I faced 2 icons from a designer that not working. Not even `fill` property. It's just invisible. Nothing helps.

I cannot provide more useful information. All icons work as is. Except for this 2. In chrome no problems.

Upd: 
https://jsfiddle.net/u0t4tupu/4/
Here an example. These two svg use different `clip-path`. But in some reason first one makes second one invisible. Try this example in FF. Delete first icon or set them same `clip-path` - `url(#svgicon-h)`. Then it works. But why?

[image]

Comment: Applying `fill` to the `<svg>` isn't gonna do anything. It should be on the `<path>`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I tried also. As i said it's working in other browsers.

Comment: Fill should be on your element and not your svg tag. the fill property is working with firefox, just tested it

You can find some examples here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes

Comment: The fact it works in other browsers does not make it valid, Fortael. You should not expect invalid properties to work in browsers and counting on them to continue to work in the ones they currently work in would also be a mistake, because you won't get an email from the browser manufacturer when it stops working on the website you coded. The email will be from the client and they will not be happy.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, okay see, others icons works in the same way in firefox. I also made rule for path tag. Even if I'm wrong then i should have default color for svg, isn't it? But it's invisible. https://jsfiddle.net/u0t4tupu/ I posted that icon. There is working. But not in context of my site. Maybe it's because icon appear after page loading? I'm using vue.js

Comment: Most likely, the `<svg>`s that do not work are invalid. Either compare the ones that work with the ones that don't to see specific differences until you find out what's wrong with the ones that don't or add a [mcve] to your question, to make it answerable. As a side-note, `<svg>`s can be quite tricky, as they are, in fact, different documents that get embedded in current markup, pretty much like `<iframe>`s. And they have specific requirements in order to work, which are probably not met by yours. I can't tell from a picture.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Hmm. This one icon comes next after svg logo in navbar where i did change color for one path. If i would delete this svg-logo, then i see my icon. Very strange behavior. Feels like `overflow` behavior, but no... they're even in different nodes. The problem in `clip-path`. But i cannot understand why

Comment: "Applying fill to the <svg> isn't gonna do anything". This advice is completely wrong. Style properties like `fill` can be inherited from ancestors.

Comment: Please post an [mcve].  We cannot help you debug half-missing pictures of code.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two elements with

```
id="svgicon-a"
```

One in each SVG.

`id` attributes **must be unique in a document**.  If there is more than one on a page the results are browser-dependent.  That is why you get a different result on Chrome than you do in Firefox.

The fix is to change the `id` in one of the SVGs.

https://jsfiddle.net/u0t4tupu/5/

Comment: Forgive my inattention. And thanks for help. This html is generated automatically by js component. So i even didn't expect this kind of problem.